# Does seeded rand() with unique integer return unique number?

Tags: php, mysql, random

There is `id` auto-increment primary key column and `serial` int column in a table. How to insert a 7 digit unique random number into `serial`?

Can we say that seeded `rand()` with unique id returns unique value?

```
FLOOR(1111111 + (RAND( <uniqe id> ) * 8888888))
```

Can it done with php `mt_srand` and `mt_rand`?

Comment: No, not guaranteed in general. Use a crypto-hash function with an output big enough so that you are okay with a failure-rate of 1/2^bits. Or somehow use a counter (maybe combined with some a-priori crypto-shuffle if you want the output appearing to be random)

Comment: @sascha like `random_int` in php? how it is unique?

Comment: I think i was quite clear. Using rng's don't expect anything (seeding is hard; huge differences between rng's). Using crypto-hashes collision is of low probability (avalanche effect), but possible (output-bit tuning probably not possible in your restricted use-case; 7 digit). Use something counter-based (you have to keep some state) if uniqueness is needed (either store some 40MB secret-permutation and map; or sample and check against already used ones; classic computation/memory trade-off).

Comment: You may want to create a question on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ to check that you aren't creating a security hole but I think you would be better off creating an hmac using the unique_id as a key and the RAND as the data and then truncate to desired length, (looping until you have a unique. Requires LOCK table t WRITE; to prevent race condition)